# How to make 404 pages using twig in CakePHP3?

Tags: cakephp

I am using Twig in Cakephp3. I can not create an error page.

I created a file `error400.twig` and `error500.twig` in the `src/Template/Error` folder. However, when accessing a strange URL, an error of nginx is displayed. I can not find the Japanese Twig help page (I am Japanese).

Comment: CakePHP doesn't use Twig, you'd have to use a plugin that adds such support, or you'd have to add support for it yourself. Withouot showing/explaining what exactly you're doing in your application with regards to Twig, you most probably won't get any (good) answers. Also whenever receiving errors, you should post the complete error message and explain how triggered it. Encountering a server error often means that it's not application related.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
> you'd have to use a plugin that adds such support, or you'd have to add support for it yourself  
I see...
Maybe I cant do...So I rewrite code.
Thank you